# Image replacement and text-align: right

Tags: html, css, image-replacement

I'm trying to do implement [image resizing techniques](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageReplacement/), and they all work very well -- that is, until you pop in a:

```
body {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mAGhh/

Has anyone dealt with this before?  I could certainly wrap all the elements and use image replacement then, but I'm pretty sure I will run into inline issues ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this to remove the text for image replacement:

```
element {
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

...and you have `text-align:right`, the negative indentation won't work right. The trick is designed to work with standard left-aligned text.

A good defensive measure is to explicitly declare `text-align:left` on the element when you do image replacement this way.